# How to query Hyperledger Fabric blockchain data outside CLI container?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using the ./byfn.sh script from the fabric-sample to start my blockchain. 
I would like to invoke and query data from a PHP website from the blockchain.

I do know that I can only use the API call from CLI container or use a JavaSDK/NodeSDK, RESTapi.

How can I query data from the blockchain the easiest way?
I am looking at NodeSDK and RestApi but I don't see much guides out there to help me, hence this question.
Sorry for the newbie questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to call and interact with Hyperledger Fabric peers is via SDK, here is the list of available SDK's:

1. Java SDK
2. GoLang SDK
3. NodeJS SDK
4. Python SDK

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @christo4ferris there is an additional project:

5. [REST SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest)

(Which might be the one you are interested in)

---

For example you can use golang SDK and do following:

1. Read configuration file

   `var err error
   conf, err := config.InitConfig("config.yaml")
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`
2. Initialize fabric client

   `cl := fabricclient.NewClient(conf)
   bccspFactory.InitFactories(conf.CSPConfig())
   cl.SetCryptoSuite(bccspFactory.GetDefault())`
3. Load client certificate and keys

   `privKey := filepath.Join(conf.CryptoConfigPath(), "path to key")
   pubKey := filepath.Join(conf.CryptoConfigPath(), "path to cert")`
4. Read and setup MSP ID

   `mspID, err := conf.MspID("org1")
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`
5. Setup client user into the context

   `user, err := fabapi.NewPreEnrolledUser(conf, privKey, pubKey, "user1", mspID, cl.GetCryptoSuite())
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }
   cl.SetUserContext(user)`
6. Setup ordering node

   `ordererConf, err := conf.OrdererConfig("orderer0")
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`

   `o, err := orderer.NewOrderer(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", ordererConf.Host, ordererConf.Port),
       filepath.Join(conf.CryptoConfigPath(), "path to orderer cert"),
       "orderer.example.com", conf)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`
7. Setup and initialize channel and the endorsing peer

   `peers, err := conf.PeersConfig("org1")
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`

   `p, err := peer.NewPeer(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", peers[0].Host, peers[0].Port), conf)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
   }`

   `ch, err := cl.NewChannel("mychannel")
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`

   `ch.AddOrderer(o)
   ch.AddPeer(p)
   ch.SetPrimaryPeer(p)
   cl.SaveUserToStateStore(user, true)`
8. Prepare transaction proposal request send it and submit for ordering

   `txRequest := apitxn.ChaincodeInvokeRequest{
       Targets:      []apitxn.ProposalProcessor{p},
       Fcn:          "myFCN",
       Args:         []string{"myargs"},
       TransientMap: map[string][]byte{},
       ChaincodeID:  "helloworld",
   }`

   `proposalResponse, _, err := ch.SendTransactionProposal(txRequest)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`

   `fmt.Printf("%v\n", proposalResponse[0].ProposalResponse)`

   `tx, err := ch.CreateTransaction(proposalResponse)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`

   `txResponse, err := ch.SendTransaction(tx)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
   }`

   `fmt.Println(txResponse[0])`

Pretty same way this will work across all SDK's.

Comment: Thank you! I have been reading up a little and decided to start of from the fabcar node sdk query tutorial :)

Comment: make sense, let us know how it goes :)

Comment: I would add a note that work has begun on a REST SDK here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest