# SimpleSample Blockchain program error while testing from SOAP UI

Tags: java, soapui, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

We are trying to implement Blockchain program using one of the sample program (`SimpleSample.JAVA`) listed out in the below link. We are able to setup the environment to execute the program in Windows10 operating system. But, when we test it from SOAPUI with URL `http:\\localhost:7050` with `HTTP METHOD GET/POST`, we get an error saying

> ERROR GETTING RESPONSE; ORG.APACHE.HTTP.NOHTTPRESPONSEEXCEPTION: THE TARGET SERVER FAILED TO RESPOND.

Need your inputs on how this can be rectified to run the Blockchain program? The Blockchain program is successfully registered with the Docker. We got stuck post trying from the URL.

Linked followed for the implementation: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html

File – SIMPLESAMPLE.JAVA

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 has no support for REST, therefore trying to connect with SoapUI won't work, hence the error you are receiving. For your convenience there are several SDK libraries provided which allows you to interact with Hyperledger Fabric peers to invoke chaincode and submit transactions for ordering. Please see list below:

1. [NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)
2. [GoLang SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)
3. [Python SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py)
4. [Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)

There is also an effort to provide REST SDK mediator, please take a look [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072704/how-to-query-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain-data-outside-cli-container/46076612#46076612) is an example of using Golang SDK to invoke chaincode on the peer, another [example is using Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774774/use-rest-api-support-in-local-development-environment-for-hyperledher-fabric-v1/45775291#45775291).

Comment: there is development on a REST SDK [1], but it is not yet ready for more than experimental use. [1] https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest

Comment: thanks @christo4ferris, I have mentioned it in my answer :)

Comment: Thanks Artem Barger. I will try with your options and update here.

Comment: Here is example of golang https://github.com/C0rWin/pgdays/blob/master/chaincode/client/client.go